# Sending Redshift Query Result in Email with Python and Airflow

Tags: html, email, amazon-redshift, airflow

I am making a daily DAG that will run a query in Redshift and will send the result table in an email.

I currently manage to take the query results and put it into a DataFrame. My problem is using `send_email` (from airflow package) and choosing the parameters for it to show the data.

The output of the email is unfortunately not a table, just the results being all over the place as text.

Here is what I wrote for `send_email` :

````
        html_content = f"""
                        <html><body><p>Hello,</p>
                        <p>Found {num_of_late_dags} Late DAGs:</p>
                        {late_dags}
                        <p>Regards,</p>
                        <p>Me</p>
                        </body></html>
                        """
        send_email(to=v_email_recipients_daily_report,
                   cc=cc,
                   bcc=bcc,
                   subject=f'Daily DAG Load Report',
                   html_content=html_content,
                   mime_subtype='alternative') ```
````

Comment: Did you try `df.to_html()` ? https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html

Comment: Thank you! I used it, but apprantly I used it wrong. Works now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I used `pd.to_html()` after `html_content` in `.format(to_html())` but that didnt work.
I used `to_html()` when creating the data as a DataFrame it worked. Not sure why, they should do the same.

So it looked like this: `df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['X',Y']).to_html()`

Then putting `df` inside the HTML content worked.